# Parsing XML file returns null

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing, null, xmlpullparser

I am trying to parse an XML file with `XMLPullParser`. My code is as follows:

```
try {
    XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

    xpp.setInput(new StringReader(iData));
    int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
    while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
        if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            if (xpp.getName() == "service") {
                sDetails[0] = xpp.getAttributeValue(1);
            }
            if (xpp.getName() == "username") {
            sDetails[1] = xpp.nextText();
            }
            if (xpp.getName() == "quota") {
            sDetails[2] = xpp.nextText();
            }
            if (xpp.getName() == "plan") {
            sDetails[5] = xpp.nextText();
            }
            if (xpp.getName() == "carrier") {
            sDetails[4] = xpp.nextText();
            }
            if (xpp.getName() == "speed") {
            sDetails[3] = xpp.nextText();
            }
            if (xpp.getName() == "usage-rating") {
            sDetails[6] = xpp.nextText();
            }
            if (xpp.getName() == "rollover") {
            sDetails[7] = xpp.nextText();
            }
            if (xpp.getName() == "excess-charged") {
            sDetails[10] = xpp.nextText();
            }
            if (xpp.getName() == "excess-shaped") {
            sDetails[11] = xpp.nextText();
            }
            if (xpp.getName() == "excess-restricted") {
            sDetails[12] = xpp.nextText();
            }
            if (xpp.getName() == "plan-interval") {
            sDetails[8] = xpp.nextText();
            }
            if (xpp.getName() == "plan-cost") {
            sDetails[9] = xpp.nextText();
            }
        }
        eventType = xpp.next();
    }
    String t = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < sDetails.length; i++) {
        t = t + sDetails[i] + ",";
    }
    return t;
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

However, when I print the value that is returned. All I get is:

```
null,null,null,null,...,null,null, (13 Times)
```

Am I missing something? The XML file that I am reading from is returned (I know, because I can print it). `iData` is a string containing the XML file. The method that I am using works for another XML file from the same location, except my `IF` statements inside the `WHILE` are different. Any suggestions as to why `null` is returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its okay. I solved it. You can't compare strings using `==`. I changed the `==` to `...getName().equals("blahblah")` and it worked.